# How can i find out what DLL's my C++ program uses?

Tags: c++, dll, sdl, release

Even when I build an exe in release mode, when I try to execute the program on another PC, I get DLL not found errors. So I need to find out which dlls my program needs and copy them with the exe. But I can't seem to figure out how to find what dlls my program uses.

```
#include "SDL.h"
#include "SDL_image.h"
#include "SDL_ttf.h"
#include "SDL_mixer.h"
#include <string>
#include "head.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <windows.h>
```

I'm pretty sure what dll's it needs is based on the includes so here they are. I know which ones are used by the SDL libraries but I don't know the others.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) might help. Have a look at the application screen-shot below.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use `dumpbin` to print all dynamic libraries required by your executable or DLL:

```
dumpbin /dependents myprog.exe
```

Typically you can find `dumpbin.exe` in directory `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio XXX\VC\bin"`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [dependence walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see whether all dependence are available before your run the exe: